# Clang/LLVM 9 and 10 SIGSEGV for inline static class members. Bug?

Tags: static, c++17, inline, llvm-clang

Using `inline static` class members in Clang gives me unexpected behaviour when the member is another class/struct:
https://godbolt.org/z/mbH6k7

```
// std=c++17
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    double a = 42;
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
};

inline static A a{}; // No problem

namespace N {
    inline static A a{}; // No problem
}

struct B {
    B() { std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
    inline static double d; // No problem with built-in types
    A& a1 = N::a; // No problem
    inline static A a2 = N::a; // No problem
    inline static A a3{}; // <-- Problem here!
};

B b1;
inline static B b2;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output, works in Clang 8.0.0, gcc, msvc:

```
A()
A()
A()
B()
B()
```

Actual output for Clang 9.0.0 and onwards: `139 (SIGSEGV)`.

Is this a bug, or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a pretty cut-and-dry bug to me:

Per **[[class.static.data]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static.data#4.sentence-3)**

> An
> inline static data member may be defined in the class definition and may specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer*.

Your code conforms to this:

```
struct B {
    // ...
    inline static A a3{};
};
```

Comment: I will file a bug report. But seems crazy to me that something this 'simple' is not caught in regression.